# How to sset up your own secure boot keys to be used

Tags: uefi, secure-boot

Im trying to get the benefits of secure boot but i dont trust MS to sign stuff.
Is there a easy way to both set up secure boot and have new kernel (i think kernel is updated via apt) get auto-signed?
(i do know how to import keys in UEFI)
(might belong on superuser for the first half but im not sure)